# Nodejs cron job / daily job 2 AM

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I have a cron in nodejs that executes every 5 hours, with this code :

```
cron.schedule("0 0 */5 * * *")
```

I want it to execute every day at 2 AM , what do I change ?

Thanks

Comment: `0 2 * * *`. [Handy cheetsheet/calculator](https://crontab.guru/#0_2_*_*_*)

Comment: @Gavin, we do not talk about UNIX/Linux cron

Answer (score 2):

You should make this line to be

```
cron.schedule("0 0 2 * * *")
```